# Reset "Sign In with Apple" to the initial create account state

Tags: ios

I am implementing Sign In with Apple and basically everything works, I don't need help with that. However, while testing my implementation, I want to reset back to before the first time I used Sign In with Apple, where it asks you if you want to create an account, and asks for the name and email address. Like this:

[image]

After you signed in that first time and then sign in again, it only asks if you want to sign in using your Apple ID, but skips the `requestedScopes`. So, how can I go back to that first state where it does ask for the `requestedScopes` info, like name and email?

Reinstalling the app didn't help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can revoke the app's permissions for your apple ID in your phone/simulator settings. I've attached the steps where you can find everything.

1. iPhone Settings, select your Apple account.

[image: iPhone Settings]

2. Password & Security

[image: Password & Security]

3. Apps Using Your Apple ID

[image: Apps Using Your Apple ID]

4. Your app/app bundle ID

[image: Your app/app bundle ID]

5. Stop using Apple ID

[image: Stop using Apple ID]

Comment: Hey @elarcoiris, any additional steps required for this to work? I'm redoing these step over and over again and my app still prompts with the "second" state and not the initial one. Why is this so annoying...

Comment: @bevoy I would also ensure you delete your app from the device and reinstall after you've done the above, just in case anything was left in memory.

Comment: @bevoy I faced the same problem as you until I realised after performing the steps described by elarcoiris I forgot to put any scopes into the ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest, so that's why the 'first' screen didn't appear. After putting 'Email' back into the scopes, the steps of elarcoiris did work.